# I can't use my jupyter notebook/jupyter lab,it's blank

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After i installed Anaconda, i input "jupyter notebook" in the terminal(Windows)
 [cmd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XIRm.png)
and the fellow page just show up for a few second then just redirect to an blank page.

[browser first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hcof.png)

[browser second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqTrx.png)

and console show:

```html
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js?v=f004a16…' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/preact/index.js?v=00a2fac…' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/proptypes/index.js?v=c40890e…' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/preact-compat/index.js?v=aea8f66…' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/requirejs/require.js?v=951f856…' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/tree/js/main.min.js?v=ab9f3a6…' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
VM27 tree:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at VM27 tree:24
```

it's all blank! And i also couldn't understand the console information.
i am not sure the problem whether have connection with installing the tensorflow-gpu. 
i try to reinstall the Anaconda.
i try to config the Windows defender and put "jupyter-notebook.exe" and "jupyter-lab.exe" into the white list.
i try try to use at least there different kind of browser.
But the problem is still there.
So anyone have the similarity problem and successfully fixed, please tell me.

Comment: Did you try changing the browser?

Comment: I found the target html file and use Edge、Firefox to open it，but it's useless.

Comment: The terminal log said there is a 302 GET...

Answer (score 1):

That is due to a bug in jupyter, you can install and use an older version untill the bug gets fixed.

https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/537

Answer (score 1):

## Notebook 5.7.6 is the cause.

user11230962 is right.  I was going after this for a long time before his comment pointed me in the right direction.  The module and version that is troublesome is `notebook 5.7.6`.

4 hours ago (10AM Central, Mar 28 2019) a new version was pushed out- there's no change log that I found.  I did try this and it didn't work.  But it may have been a caching issue.  Because the below didn't work right away.  I had to close all the open tabs and retry.  Then success.

## TLDR

Specifically run this and you're good to go,

```
py -3 -m pip uninstall -y notebook
py -3 -m pip install -Iv notebook==5.7.5
# or
py -3 -m pip install -Iv notebook==5.7.5 --force-reinstall
```

### more

Or however you choose, remove notebook and reinstall `notebook==5.7.5`.  I did not personally try the second command but it should work. Note, this is how I run pip on Windows, with multiple py versions- I use py.exe which is on path if you enabled the option while installing, I think it was python 2.7 (but its one or the other).  Tweak the front of your command to adjust for how you do it.

### Edit: I revisited 5.7.7- it resolves the problem.

You can also update to solve the problem.  So its even simpler

`py -3 -m   pip install -U notebook`

should work, in one command.  I suspected that I needed to restart the browser when I updated.

Answer (score 1):

i finally solved the problem, the reason is the last time i uninstall the previous Anaconda but did't change the notebook kernel's path,i think that kernel was broken.
(i change the other path when i install the current Anaconda)
So i delete the previous notebook kernel and install the new kernel,and now it can work~

Answer (score 0):

### nodejs and npm being outdated was the cause of my issue.

Started at a new role. The box couldn't serve up jupyter lab pages. Spent a bunch of time investigating the issue, looking at differential diagnoses, etc. I could get it running through miniconda, docker stacks, etc. but not directly from the machine.

It turns out that the issue was that nodejs and npm on CentOS aren't to their latest version, and the jupyter lab build was incompatible with node version < 8.

Hope that saves someone more than a couple of days.